# memcpy and std components like map: runtime failer

Tags: c++, c

I have an old C library I try to modify. There is a line like:

```
memcpy(&m_agents[idx].params, params, sizeof(dtCrowdAgentParams));
```

And ofcourse C stule pod like values and structs get copied. But I tried to add to `params.some_struct.some_inner_map_field` `std::map` and it does not get initialised on memcpy.

So I wonder how to copy my map keeping it alive? (if possible not extending methods of `params` and `params.some_struct`)

Comment: `m_agents[idx].params = *params;` -- Does that not work?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: it is intresting - it fails same way at runtime as with memcpy. with such last callstack line: `App.exe!std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<int,float,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,float> >,0> >::_Copy(const std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<int,float,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,float> >,0> > & _Right={...})  Line 1501 + 0xf bytes C++`

Comment: I'll need to see a more complete example that demonstrates the problem then.

Answer (score 1):

I would need to see the full definition of the struct to be sure, but this should work:

```
m_agents[idx].params = *params;
```

For POD types, it will do the same thing as memcpy.  For non-POD types, it will call their assignment operator.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing it with

```
m_agents[idx].params = *params;
```

will correct that instance. However, it's reasonable to suppose that the C library you are working with is assuming POD throughout and so you will need to check the whole codebase to ensure it's not doing anything that will break things elsewhere.

Are your maps mutable within the library or can you treat them as constant while the library is handling the data? If you can treat them as constant consider passing a handle, or pointer, to you map into the library instead of including the map itself in the parameter struct.